# Can PHP 5.4 run on PHP 5.3 configured server

Tags: php, mysql

First of all, I am a novice web developer.

My question is "A website developed with PHP 5.4 can run on PHP 5.3 configured server?"

(Detail Description) 
I configure myself Apache 2.4, MySQL 5.6 and PHP 5.4.12 on Windows. Everything's ok. But the errors occur when I changed my website folder to another machine which is configured with WAMPserver. This WAMPserver is configured with Apache 2.2.11, PHP 5.3 and MySQL 5.1.36.

I install MySQL 5.6 on this machine and database is successfully connected. But the "Parse error occur to the code" such as

`$country = mysql_fetch_row(queryMySQL("----"))[0];`

In addition, it showed other errors such as "Table 'emp.productcateogry' doesn't exist".

Please, give me some suggestions.

Comment: PHP 5.3.x doesn't support access to array returns on function calls - thus the error.

Comment: All I know is that combining an older version with a new version and expecting it to work is sketchy.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: no, you should not expect it to, especially if using the [new features](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) of PHP 5.4 within your code.

The specific error you are referring to with:

> Parse error occur to the code

is because the line

```
$country = mysql_fetch_row(queryMySQL("----"))[0];
```

is using the new feature:

> Function array dereferencing

Which, prior to PHP 5.4, had to use a temporary variable in order to access a specific index of the return, ie:

```
$country_temp = mysql_fetch_row(queryMySQL("----"));
$country = $country_temp[0];
```

Now, being that you are a novice developer, there are a few things you should note.  The first and most important being that `mysql_` functions are [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) giving the note:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

In other words, use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) if wanting to use prepared statements, or [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) if not.  Another advantage of using PDO and obtaining only one column as you are in the example code is that once you are connected, you can use the function [`PDOStatement::fetchColumn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) to obtain only one column like you are trying to do now.

Anyways, I hope this explanation helps you understand why you can't go back to PHP 5.3.x if using specific PHP 5.4 abilities - and also some understanding of how to improve your database connection and available functions that can help you get your desired result without using the "array dereferencing" that is provided with PHP 5.4. ^^

Comment: The temporary variable isn't necessary in this case. One can use `list($country) = mysql_fetch_row(...)`.

Comment: While true, introducing [`list`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to a programmer who isn't that familiar with the language might cause confusion as to how it operates.  Using a temporary variable shows a direct line of assignment in the way that OP was familiar with. ^^